# Moving point mass m on a moving cirlce

Tags: physics, cylindrical-coordinates

[Mass m attached to wheel rolling on a surface (no slip).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDv7L.png)

A mass m is attached to the perimeter of wheel of radius b. The wheel is massless, except for a
point mass M at its center. The radius of the wheel is b.

The task is to find the velocity of the point mass as a function of $\theta$ and $\dot{\theta}$

The solution sheet gives this

$v^2=2b^2\dot{\theta}^2[1-cos(\theta)]$

As well as giving the initial positions

$x = b\theta - bsin(\theta)$

$y = b - b\cos(\theta)$

What I am struggling to understand is how they find the $x$ coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

The solution sheet assumes that the origin is at the centre of the circle at the instant when $m$ is directly below $M$.

When the wheel has rotated an angle $\theta$ without slipping, the point of contact of the circle with the floor is at a horizontal distance from the origin equal to the arc length between $m$ and the point of contact at this instant. This distance is $b\theta$.

Therefore, the horizontal displacement of $m$ from the origin is $$b\theta-b\sin\theta$$